# How to be overflow the row of table?

Tags: asp.net, html

I created a webpage with the uploaded files and the uploading control in asp.net. I got a problem that is design problem.

```
<table style="width:500px;height:500px">
   <tr>
      <td>Uploading page<td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="height:300px;overflow:auto">
         <asp:Repeater ID="UploadedFileList" runat="server">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <%# Eval("FileName") %>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>
      <td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want to be overflow the sencod row. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep another DIV inside the td to work better in this situation.

```
<table style="width:500px;height:500px">
   <tr>
      <td>Uploading page<td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="height:300px;">
         <div style="height:300px;overflow:auto">
         <asp:Repeater ID="UploadedFileList" runat="server">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <%# Eval("FileName") %>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
      <td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Check the updated code, you should keep a div and apply the style to that for better scroll feature